# Efficient Input Handling with std::vector buffers

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to find a fast way to do input but I've learned that using STL for such purposes might be slow.

I have a callback that fires whenever I get Keyboard input.
It creates an object with `(int _key, int _state, int _life)`

Everytime I receive this callback, I `push_back` the object to my std::vector;

Every frame I check the top of this vector and remove the "dead" input.

The vector can be polled for whatever input is valid at that moment which means it will be searched frequently.

Optimizations:

-All the memory should be contiguous so although Link Lists are better for dynamic allocation, should I stick with STL's vector? I'm always adding to the top and removing from the bottom so what data struct should I use?

-I was thinking of having a buffer(second vector) that continuously receives new input from the callback, then each frame copy the data from that vector to the top of my active input vector. Since the active vector will be polled, would this increase performance since it won't be wasting time getting added to during the loop?

Basically I'm trying to squeeze as much performance from this vector as possible and I could use some help.

Comment: If your memory must be contiguous, then `std::vector` is the only option. You can use a [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) together with `std::vector`.

Comment: Could you explain that further in an answer?

Comment: *although Link Lists are better for dynamic allocation* => they are not, lucky you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing, adding data in one end, removing in another, is the archetypical description of a queue. This is implemented in the standard library with the [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) class.

This queue class is a so-called container adapter, meaning it uses another container for the actual storage. By default it uses [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque), but that container doesn't keep its data in a contiguous memory area. However you can declare a `std::queue` with almost any other standard container, like `std::vector` (which is the only container guaranteed to store data in a contiguous memory area):

```
std::queue<int, std::vector> my_queue_with_vector;
my_queue_with_vector.push(1);
my_queue_with_vector.push(2);
my_queue_with_vector.push(3);

while (!my_queue_with_vector.empty())
{
    std::cout << my_queue_with_vector.top() << '\n';
    my_queue_with_vector.pop();  // Remove top element in the queue
}
```

Comment: Except... you can't really use a queue with a `std::vector`, as it doesn't support pop_front. From the description of `queue` "Any sequence container supporting operations front(), back(), push_back() and pop_front() can be
used to instantiate queue."  `vector` doesn't support pop_front.

Answer (score 3):

`std::deque` makes the best container. It guarantees O(1) pop_front and push_back() *and* has random access and a good degree (although not completely) of cache behaviour.

But if you absolutely must have complete contiguity, then you'll need to look into a custom circular buffer container (there's one in Boost IIRC), as pop_front() on a `vector` is rather expensive.

Edit: As another poster has pointed out, keyboard input is so infrequent even for a very fast typist that I find it difficult to believe that this is a bottleneck in your system.

Comment: Im more interested in best practices for a high traffic scenario where issue could be an issue. Another user states that a vector might still be faster, do you agree?

Comment: Only a profiler can answer for certain, but `std::deque` has superior algorithmic properties for this usage, so given an arbitrarily large amount of traffic, it will be the winner.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a `std::deque`. Adjacents elements are nearly always allocated continuously in memory and it has constant time insertion and removal at begin and end.

Comment: I will look into this. Sounds promising.

Comment: Unfortunately [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) do not keep its data in a contiguous memory area.

Comment: @Joachim I don't think this was a hard requirement, more of an idea to optimize performance.

Comment: @JoshElias: I advise you to edit your question and add a note about contiguity not being necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: It doesn't matter. std::vector and std::list can easily handle millions of insert operations per second, but most typists don't type faster than 10 characters per second on a keyboard.

Long answer: push_back and erase are usually very cheap on a vector if the vector is small (< 100) and the copy/swap operations of the objects stored on the vector are  cheap. The allocations used to insert into or remove from an std:list are usually more expensive. If it becomes an issue, measure the cost.

An std::deque also has allocations and depending on the implementation is likely more expensive than the vector in your case, if my assumption that your vector rarely if ever contains more than 10 items - all of which are cheap to copy - is correct.

Comment: It could be that the keys are stored in a buffer and are being played back. It may not be a 'live' typing scenario. Of course, it is an assumption

Comment: So a vector would be faster than a deque? 10 items at once sounds like a accurate guess. I would only be using push_back and pop_front.

Comment: Yes a vector would be faster, but it does depend on both the implementation of the stl and the type of ojects the vector contains. In your case it seems pop_front is a memcopy over one or two cache lines, which is about as cheap as it gets.If there's an issue, you should measure the actual time lost on this.